# Trying to extract metaData from URL

Tags: swift, metadata, avasset, avplayeritem

I am developing a live music streaming application for iOS. What I am trying to do is, extracting the metadata values of the music that is currently playing. Metadata is stored in the URL. Write now I am able to extract this as metaData.

```
 Optional([<AVMetadataItem: 0x600001c69860, identifier=common/title, keySpace=comn, key class = __NSCFConstantString, key=title,
 commonKey=title, extendedLanguageTag=(null), dataType=(null),
 time={19392/22050 = 0.879}, duration={INVALID}, startDate=(null),
 extras={ }, value class=__NSCFString, value=Electricity - Silk City &
 Dua Lipa f./Diplo - 03:39 >])
```

The problem is there is only one common key ie "title" in the metadata item.  This common key has a value that consist of song title, artist and song duration.  How do I extract only the artist value from this common key..

This is how am I extracting metadata.

I added an observer to the AVPlayerItem for key path "timedMetadata"

```
playerItem.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "timedMetadata", options: [], context: nil)




 override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {


    if keyPath != "timedMetadata" { return }

    var data: AVPlayerItem = object as! AVPlayerItem

    for item in data.timedMetadata as! [AVMetadataItem] {


        if let stringValue = item.value as? String {
            //print(item.commonKey)
            if item.commonKey!.rawValue == "title" {
                print(stringValue.description)
            }



        }

    }


}
```

Getting this as value : `Electricity - Silk City & Dua Lipa f./Diplo - 03:39`

This value has the song title, song artists, and song duration. What I want is to get only the song artist as the value. metadata changes it value for each song that is currently being played.

Comment: I guess that using https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_assets_playback_and_editing/finding_metadata_values and the target https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avmetadatakey?language=objc you should be able to get only the artist. But if the audio item doesn't provide good info (mixing Title + Author + Duration) in the `title` part, you need to parse it yourself, but that's might change for each item.

Comment: have gone through the apple documentation, and still not able to figure a way to solve this problem.  Is it possible to extract just the author if the audio has single common key.?

Answer (score -1):

Finally have found a way around to solve this problem..

The value i was getting was separated by a common character (-). What I did is converted this single string into array of strings.

```
let stringValueArray = stringValue.components(separatedBy: "-")

                let title = stringValueArray[0]

                let author = stringValueArray[1]

                let duration = stringValueArray[2]
```

I know this might not be the right approach, but still it works..